# Поменять текст кнопки на последнем тесте

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня не выходит поменять название кнопки так, чтобы на последнем тесте она называлась "Посмотреть результаты", а у меня выводит только название из HTML файла. Я пыталась как-то скрыть кнопку, или сравнением (currentQuiz == quizData.length) вывести её, но пока ничего не вышло

Моя реализация была такой:

```
<div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="quiz-header">
                    <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer">
                          <label for="a" id="a_text">Answer</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer">
                          <label for="b" id="b_text">Answer</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer">
                          <label for="c" id="c_text">Answer</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer">
                          <label for="d" id="d_text">Answer</label>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button id="submit" >Наступне питання</button>
                  </div>
```

```
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const answer = getSelected()
    if(answer) 
    {  
        currentQuiz++
        // Увеличивает процент прогресса при прохождении теста
        progress += 5;
        progressBar.style.width = `${progress}%`;

        if (currentQuiz < quizData.length) 
        {
        loadQuiz()
        } 
        else if (currentQuiz == quizData.length)
                {
                    document.getElementById('submit').hidden = true;
                    quiz.innerHTML = `<button onclick="showResult()"> Дивитися результат </button> `
                }
    }
})
```

Comment: нет, не целиком, просто поменять текст. Чтобы на последнем тесте, кнопка называлась "посмотреть результат" а не "следующий вопрос"..

Comment: <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz"> 
это мой контейнер с вопросами и вариантами к ним, там и кнопка в конце лежит

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы всё осталось, и чтобы на кнопке был текст "посмотреть результат", т.к. это последний тест, и больше вопросов не будет

Comment: так оно и произошло..вот не знаю, как исправить так, как мне нужно..